# Debug ACPI calls

Tags: linux, debugging, acpi

I recently bought new laptop (HP Omen) with RGB keyboard which can be customized done only by special app for Windows OS. I'm Linux user and want to customize it from my favorite distro. I have some experience debugging ACPI in Linux, but not in Windows. I think there are several approaches to control kb light. It can be stored in NVRAM or in special memory of 
hardware.

How i can debug those things? Maybe there some specific methods in DSDT?

`/sys/class/leds` doesn't contain a keyboard and all vendor specific kernel modules are loaded (hp_wmi, hp_accel, hp_wireless).

Comment: I guess you need to look to WMI interface.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for answer! Can you give some links where i can read more about WMI? I’ve discovered that leds controlled from WMI methods, but i didn’t work with WMI and don’t know how to debug it under Windows

Answer (score 0):

keyboard? from my experience, you can get/set EC RAM access to reach it.

Comment: Hello! How to reach the EC RAM of keyboard? Thanks

Comment: It should have a ACPI EC driver with CID PNP0C09, if it is there under windows device manager
- check EC operation via RW tool, for read/write, you can use 62/66 index/data port for giving a try to see keyboard's response or not.